# Questions and Answers related to TVs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site in the entire stack exchange that I could ask for information about TV products?

I am trying to buy a Smart TV that suits my needs and a Q&A site like that would help a lot.

Unless this could be considered advertising and then yes I understand why you don't deploy such a site.

From a first look at the titles on the site http://stackexchange.com I could not find any.

Comment: +1 For looking around first, and not posting directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a site in the entire stack exchange that I could ask for information about TV products?

At the moment, there isn't. You could go over to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and post a site proposal *#. TVs and specifically Smart TVs, are not covered in any SE site and a new proposal wouldn't hurt.

> I am trying to buy a Smart TV that suits my needs and a Q&A site like that would help a lot.

That is the exact [shopping type question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) that SE doesnt want. *If you want to create a site proposal, then it would have to be about using TVs and related products, and not about TV recommendations.

`#` TVs are covered under the [Consumer Electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) proposal as pointed out by LBT

Comment: wouldn't TVs fall under [consumer electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics)?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, these would be the exact embodiments of [shopping questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and as such off-topic on all the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Ah, it's not often the shopping request post gets linked to for an *actual* shopping request! It's usually linked to for book recommendations / toolsets etc.